# Ansible - Setting iptable rules locks me out of SSH

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I've created the following `iptables` rules using Ansible's iptable module.

Previous to using Ansible I had the following rules in a bash script. The SSH lockout was temporary because even though it locked me out the entire script would run and open up port `22`.

I'm having trouble achieving this with ansible. As soon as the `DROP` rules are applied the SSH locks out forever and the rest of the rules are unable to run.

Any way to get around this in Ansible?

```
- iptables: 
    chain: INPUT
    jump: DROP

- iptables:
    chain: FORWARD
    jump: DROP

- iptables:
    chain: OUTPUT
    jump: DROP

- iptables:
    chain: INPUT
    cstate: RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    jump: ACCEPT

- iptables:
    chain: OUTPUT
    cstate: RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    jump: ACCEPT

- iptables:
    chain: INPUT
    in_interface: lo
    jump: ACCEPT

- iptables:
    chain: OUTPUT
    in_interface: lo
    jump: ACCEPT

- iptables:
    chain: OUTPUT
    protocol: tcp
    destination_port: 53
    jump: ACCEPT

- iptables:
    chain: OUTPUT
    protocol: udp
    destination_port: 53
    jump: ACCEPT 

- iptables:
    chain: INPUT
    protocol: tcp
    destination_port: 53
    jump: ACCEPT

- iptables:
    chain: INPUT
    protocol: udp
    destination_port: 53
    jump: ACCEPT

- iptables:
    chain: INPUT
    protocol: tcp
    destination_port: 22
    jump: ACCEPT

- iptables:
    chain: OUTPUT
    protocol: tcp
    destination_port: 22
    jump: ACCEPT

- iptables:
    chain: INPUT
    protocol: tcp
    destination_port: 80
    jump: ACCEPT

- iptables:
    chain: OUTPUT
    protocol: tcp
    destination_port: 80
    jump: ACCEPT

- iptables:
    chain: INPUT
    protocol: tcp
    destination_port: 443
    jump: ACCEPT

- iptables:
    chain: OUTPUT
    protocol: tcp
    destination_port: 443
    jump: ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't think it's possible not to be kicked out by iptables after the drop...

Anyway, Ansible does not handle the saving and/or loading of rules, but rather only manipulates the current rules that are present in memory.

Ansible's [official example](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-examples/blob/master/lamp_haproxy/roles/common/tasks/main.yml#L40) suggests using template.

```
- name: insert iptables template
  template: src=iptables.j2 dest=/etc/sysconfig/iptables
  when: ansible_distribution_major_version != '7'
  notify: restart iptables
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the order of your `iptables` calls to do allows that allow you access first:

```
# put these two rules first so that
# ansible can stay connected
- iptables:
    chain: OUTPUT
    protocol: tcp
    destination_port: 22
    jump: ACCEPT    

- iptables:
    chain: INPUT
    cstate: RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    jump: ACCEPT

# Now do all your more restrictive rules
- iptables: 
    chain: INPUT
    jump: DROP

- iptables:
    chain: FORWARD
    jump: DROP

- iptables:
    chain: OUTPUT
    jump: DROP

- iptables:
    chain: OUTPUT
    cstate: RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    jump: ACCEPT

- iptables:
    chain: INPUT
    in_interface: lo
    jump: ACCEPT

- iptables:
    chain: OUTPUT
    in_interface: lo
    jump: ACCEPT

- iptables:
    chain: OUTPUT
    protocol: tcp
    destination_port: 53
    jump: ACCEPT

- iptables:
    chain: OUTPUT
    protocol: udp
    destination_port: 53
    jump: ACCEPT 

- iptables:
    chain: INPUT
    protocol: tcp
    destination_port: 53
    jump: ACCEPT

- iptables:
    chain: INPUT
    protocol: udp
    destination_port: 53
    jump: ACCEPT

- iptables:
    chain: INPUT
    protocol: tcp
    destination_port: 22
    jump: ACCEPT

- iptables:
    chain: INPUT
    protocol: tcp
    destination_port: 80
    jump: ACCEPT

- iptables:
    chain: OUTPUT
    protocol: tcp
    destination_port: 80
    jump: ACCEPT

- iptables:
    chain: INPUT
    protocol: tcp
    destination_port: 443
    jump: ACCEPT

- iptables:
    chain: OUTPUT
    protocol: tcp
    destination_port: 443
    jump: ACCEPT
```